# Ordering relation with no dependency on success with Puppet

Tags: require, puppet

Adding a `require` relation with Puppet means the current resource will be skipped if the required dependencies fails.

**Is it possible to keep the ordering relation but continue the execution even if the dependency failed?**

Typically, I want to trigger a build after upgrading a package list. If the internet connection is down, the `package` resource will likely fail but I'd like the build to happen anyway. I initially though that was the point of `subscribe`, but there doesn't seem to be any difference with `require` in my case.

Comment: I read https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!msg/puppet-users/tM37SRqKgWs/gBALJBBlDdoJ but the following actions that actually need the dependency to succeed will fail. That is why I need this separation between hard and soft dependencies.

Comment: You might try manifest ordering. Not clear to me if that creates a "soft" dependency or not. http://puppetlabs.com/blog/introducing-manifest-ordered-resources http://docs.puppetlabs.com/learning/ordering.html#unrelated-resources-and-the-ordering-setting

Comment: Thanks, but this workaround is not enough for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is simply no way to do that, and this is against Puppet's design.

I managed to fix my issue by:

- reordering dependencies so there is a single action to do after the *soft* dependency
- using the `|| true` workaround mentioned on the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!msg/puppet-users/tM37SRqKgWs/gBALJBBlDdoJ).

**Edit**: In the end, that wasn't really maintainable. Switched to [Ansible](http://www.ansible.com/home).

Comment: So the dependency that might fail is an `exec` and you didn't think to mention that in the question?

Comment: No, I didn't. Does this change anything (except allowing a horrible workaround which is already stated in the link above)?